# How to use tailwind with ExpressJS & EJS template?

Tags: css, express, ejs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use tailwind for my project, But I'm using ExpressJS, and EJS as a view engine, but It is not working, any guide?

My app.js file

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const ejs = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const port = 3000;
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "src"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.render("homepage");
});

app.listen(port, (req, res) => {
console.log("Server running");
});
```

My homepage.ejs file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" 
 />
    <link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Server is running successfully

Command used to generate the tailwind file

```
  npx tailwindcss -i ./src/style.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

My Project structure:

```
Project/
    -- node_modules
    -- src/
       -- index.html
       -- style.css
     -- views/
        -- homepage.ejs
```

tailwind.config.js configuration

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/*.{html,js,css} ",
    "./views/homepage.ejs",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  ],
};
```

[homepage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOcaq.png)

Comment: What's not working? Do you see an error?

Comment: @code In homepage.ejs file I have included generated output.css file in the head, then in the body, I'm using  <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>, On my server, I'm getting just Hello World as output, without style applied, Text is not bolded, and underlined. I'm not getting any error in the console or terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this doesn't work because you didn't exposed the dist folder in your Express app.

Indeed, you expose the `src` folder but not the `dist` folder that contains your styles.

Also, you did exposed the src folder but not the views ! I think that your Express app is showing you the `index.html` page from the `src` folder instead of rendering the EJS.

Based on [this demo repository with Pug](https://github.com/catalinpit/nodejs-tailwind),
I suggest you to do these changes in your Express entry point.

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const ejs = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const port = 3000;
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// => Here we expose the views so it can be rendered.
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
// => Here we expose your dist folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("homepage");
});

app.listen(port, (req, res) => {
  console.log("Server running");
});
```

and then link the CSS in your view, with `<link href="/output.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

also, if you wish to add more views in the future, I'll suggest to add a wildcard so it takes every `.ejs` file in the views folder.

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/*.{html,js,css}",
    "./views/*.ejs",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  ],
};
```

You can see a more in depth article here, https://daily.dev/blog/how-to-use-tailwindcss-with-node-js-express-and-pug.
It is for Pug, but you just need to replace every `pug` by `ejs` and you're done.

Hope it helps !